# Why spring-jdbc use "set autocommit = 0;" to start a transaction instead of "start transaction"

Tags: database, transactions, spring-jdbc

I found the database of service has lots of "set autocommit =0/1" statement; I do a little research and found that its from spring-jdbc. It's about the function Transaction; In DataSourceTransactionManager.java the doBegin method has code as this

```
            if (con.getAutoCommit()) {
                txObject.setMustRestoreAutoCommit(true);
                if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.logger.debug("Switching JDBC Connection [" + con + "] to manual commit");
                }

                con.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
```

It seems that spring-jdbc start a transaction by statement "set autocommit = 0". Indeed "set autocommit = 0" behave almost same as "start transaction". however, the more explicitly way to start a transaction is to execute "start transaction".
so why spring-jdbc use "set autocommit = 0;" to start a transaction instead of "start transaction"? And which statement would run faster?

the reason why spring-jdbc use "set autocommit = 0;" to start a transaction instead of "start transaction" and the efficiency difference between these two statment.